# How can I combine multiple rows into one column using PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

How can I combine multiple results into one column?

For example, my query displays this result:

```
internaldocid | document id | versionid | title | tagname
1146 | DOC-1146 | 2 | Press Release | tag1
1146 | DOC-1146 | 2 | Press Release | tag2
1146 | DOC-1146 | 2 | Press Release | tag3
```

I would like it to display this result:

```
internaldocid | document id | versionid | title | tagname
1146 | DOC-1146 | 2 | Press Release | tag1, tag2, tag3
```

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT
  cmsdocument.internaldocid,
  cmsdocument.documentid,
  cmsdocument.versionid,
  cmsdocversion.title,
  cmstag.tagname
FROM 
  public.cmsobjecttag,
  public.cmstag,
  public.cmsdocument,
  public.cmsdocversion,
  public.cmsuser
WHERE 
  cmsobjecttag.tagid = cmstag.tagid AND
  cmsobjecttag.objectid = cmsdocument.internaldocid AND
  cmsdocument.internaldocid = cmsdocversion.internaldocid AND
  cmsdocument.userid = cmsuser.userid AND
  cmsdocversion.state = 'published' AND
  cmsobjecttag.objecttype = '102';
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: take a look pivot table... http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2013/06/27/Pivoting-in-Postgres/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since PostgreSQL version 9, this is done simply by using [string_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES):

```
SELECT
  cmsdocument.internaldocid,
  cmsdocument.documentid,
  cmsdocument.versionid,
  cmsdocversion.title,
  string_agg(cmstag.tagname, ',')
FROM 
  public.cmsobjecttag,
  public.cmstag,
  public.cmsdocument,
  public.cmsdocversion,
  public.cmsuser
WHERE 
  cmsobjecttag.tagid = cmstag.tagid AND
  cmsobjecttag.objectid = cmsdocument.internaldocid AND
  cmsdocument.internaldocid = cmsdocversion.internaldocid AND
  cmsdocument.userid = cmsuser.userid AND
  cmsdocversion.state = 'published' AND
  cmsobjecttag.objecttype = '102'
GROUP BY 
  cmsdocument.internaldocid,
  cmsdocument.documentid,
  cmsdocument.versionid,
  cmsdocversion.title
```

Comment: @Curtis don't forget to upvote the helping answers and to accept the answer that best suits your needs.